# Weak Jacobi Forms and Siegel Modular Forms

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, modular-forms

Given a Siegel modular form $F = F(\tau, z, \sigma)$ of weight $k$ and degree 2 with respect to $Sp_{4}(\mathbb{Z})$, we have the *Fourier-Jacobi expansion*:

$$F(\tau, z, \sigma) = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \varphi_{k,m}(\tau, z) p^{m},$$

where $p=e^{2 \pi i \sigma}$ and $\varphi_{k,m}$ is a *holomorphic* Jacobi form of weight $k$ and index $m$.  Is there a theory or collection of examples where holomorphic Jacobi forms are replaced by **weak** Jacobi forms?  I have an inkling it should give rise to meromorphic Siegel modular forms perhaps.  But the literature seems remarkably sparse here, unless I am looking in the wrong places.

(One avenue I understand and am not particularly interested in for this question is the relationship between the elliptic genus of K3 (a weak Jacobi form of weight 0 and index 1) with the Igusa cusp form $\chi_{10}(\tau, z, \sigma)$.  I would be more interested in examples involving $\varphi_{-2,1}$ the unique weak Jacobi form of weight -2 and index 1.)